# How to make modal images work on auto image slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, modal-dialog

So there is auto changing images in my website and  here's what I need:
When I click on the image, modal image gallery should appear. But only one picture working out of all in auto slider. I don't know how to make other pictures to pop up like the first one and I don't know how to make slider when modal is already "turned on" or how should I say...

This is javascript.

```
    <script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000);    
}
</script>

<script>

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

 caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

THE CODE:
https://jsfiddle.net/y1Lw0k9d/3/

Answer (score 0):

An ID should be used only once per page in HTML, instead of giving your images the ID myImg, try using a class. You do this right in the carousel function.

However before attaching the click handler, you use getElementById, which returns a single element. You should get the images using the class name, and loop through the array to attach the handler to every image.

To change the image in the modal, simply change the SRC of the modal image in the carousel function. This way the modal image is always the same as the other slider. Maybe add or change some CSS for some effects.

I'm not writing up any actual code, because looking at your code you look smart enough to write it up yourself and learn from it.